# variable assigned when it is assigned

Tags: python, oop

I have defined players_turn outside of the class. But I get local variable referenced before assignment error for players_turn when function is called.
This is not all the code but this code is where players_turn shows up.
I have done something similiar with a different variable but it has worked out.

```
team_player_hp = [100,100,100,100]
players_turn = 1
class projectile:

    def turn_system(self):
        while team_player_hp[0] + team_player_hp[1] > 0 or team_player_hp[2] +  team_player_hp[3] > 0:
            if team_player_hp[players_turn % 4] == 0:
                #will skip to other player in team if first player checked has zero healthpoints
                players_turn = players_turn + 2
            x , y = team_coordinates[players_turn][0], team_coordinates[players_turn][1]
            projectile_arrow(2)
            self.player_turn = players_turn + 1
```

The variable should be assigned with function allowing the code to work.

Comment: If you assign to a variable anywhere inside a function, it is considered local. If you want it to be global, you need to explicitly mark it as such: `def turn_system(self): global players_turn`. (Although it's best to avoid global variables altogether.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that you're trying to modify the value of `players_turn` inside the `turn_system` method without explicitly declaring it as a global variable. When a variable is assigned a new value inside a function, Python assumes it's a local variable unless specified otherwise.

To resolve this, you need to explicitly declare `players_turn` as a global variable within the `turn_system` method. Here's how you can modify your code:

```py
team_player_hp = [100, 100, 100, 100]
players_turn = 1

class projectile:
    def turn_system(self):
        global players_turn
        while team_player_hp[0] + team_player_hp[1] > 0 or team_player_hp[2] + team_player_hp[3] > 0:
            if team_player_hp[players_turn % 4] == 0:
                # will skip to the other player in the team if the first player checked has zero health points
                players_turn = players_turn + 2
            x, y = team_coordinates[players_turn][0], team_coordinates[players_turn][1]
            projectile_arrow(2)
            self.player_turn = players_turn + 1
```

By adding `global players_turn` at the beginning of the `turn_system` method, you explicitly inform Python that you are referring to the global variable `players_turn` rather than creating a new local variable.

> ***Note:** Using global variables in this way can sometimes lead to code that is harder to understand and maintain. If possible, consider using class attributes or passing the necessary variables as parameters to avoid relying on global variables.*